# Make plain table from hierarchy table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a table with id, parent_id and name fields,
I need to covert it to "plain"-view.
See example:

Table "t_obj" with 2-level hierarchy:

```
Id Parent_Id Name
1  0          Build1
2  1          Work1
3  1          Work2   
4  0          Build2
5  4          Work1
6  4          Work2
```

Result "plain"-table:

```
Level1     Level2      
Build1     Work1   
Build1     Work2  
Build2     Work1  
Build2     Work2
```

It's easy to make this table via this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  public.t_obj."Name",
  t_obj1."Name"
FROM
  public.t_obj t_obj1
  INNER JOIN public.t_obj ON (t_obj1."Parent_id" = public.t_obj."Id")
```

The question is: How to make this result ("plain"-table) if I have N-level hierarchy?
 For example for this table:

```
Id Parent_Id Name
1  0          Build1
2  1          Work1
3  1          Work2   
4  0          Build2
5  4          Work1
6  4          Work2  
7  6          SubWork1
8  7          SubSubWork1
9  8          SubSubSubWork1
........
```

Result should be some like this:

```
Level1     Level2  Level3    Level4       Level5    
Build1     Work1   Null      Null         Null
Build1     Work2   Null      Null         Null
Build2     Work1   Null      Null         Null 
Build2     Work2   SubWork1  SubSubWork1  SubSubSubWork1
```

But I have no idea how to write an SQL query to get this result.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive CTE for this.

The following basically does what you want, but it puts the hierarchy information in an array rather than in separate columns.  This makes it much more extensible for deeper hierarchies:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id as leaf_id, parent_id, name, array[name] as names, 1 as lev
      from t_obj t
      where not exists (select 1 from t_obj t2 where t2.parent_id = t.id)
      union all
      select cte.leaf_id, t.parent_id, t.name, array(t.name) || cte.names, cte.lev + 1
      from cte join
           t_obj t
           on cte.parent_id = t.id
     )
select distinct on (leaf_id) cte.*
from cte
order by leaf_id, lev desc;
```

Of course, you can extract the array elements into separate columns if you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=679c67b2cc6dff3f2726cf1c3f3f601c) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

You can extract the values like this:

```
select distinct on (leaf_id) name, names[2], names[3], names[4]
from cte
order by leaf_id, lev desc
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c262ffda8f87126a00a063ace698dee5) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: But I do not need Array, I need separate columns. Can you give an example to convert array to columns?

Comment: Thank's for example "select distinct on (leaf_id) name, names[2], names[3], names[4]" But what should I do if I do not know how many leaves do I have? This is the main problem. Can you give an example for n-leaves?

Comment: @user2078264 . . . That is why I recommend arrays.  SQL queries cannot have a variable number of columns.  You have to decide when you write the query how many columns you want.

Comment: Is it possible to write a function in postgresql that generates an SQL-query as text with the necessary column numbers and then executes it?